# Why is ($dx)^2$ tiny quantity of $x^2$ and not of $x?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, terminology, math-history

When we say `dx` we are referring to a tiny quantity of $ x$ . And from literature the $(dx)^2$ is a tiny quantity of $x^2$
This is the part I am not clear about.
A minute is $\frac{1}{60}$ of an hour so we could denote $\frac{1}{60}$ as $dx$ and the hour as $x$
Now a second $(\frac{1}{60})^2$ is a tiny quantity of a minute and therefore a tiny quantity of a tiny quantity of an hour.
But I already said that hour is $x$.
So how can we also say that it is a tiny quantity of $x^2$? (which is I guess $hour^2$?)

Comment: $dx^2$ is not the same as $\left ( dx \right )^2 $

Comment: @Bombadil:I updated OP. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I updated OP. I am always talking about $(dx)^2$

Answer (score 2):

We don't have good intuition about what time-squared means, so maybe you should use length, since length squared is area.  If you had a square which was $x$-by-$x$ feet and then increased both sides by $dx$, then the area of your new square is $x^2 +2x \; dx+ (dx)^2$.  The change in the area is two skinny $x$-by-$dx$ strips and then a little corner piece of area $(dx)^2.$  So it's not really the change in $x^2$, but it's a measure of how much the change in $x^2$ is not linear.

Or you could just consider the skinny strip.  Then $(dx)^2$ is (sort of) the change from $x$-by-$dx$ to $x+dx$-by-$dx$.

As others have said, it takes a decent sized pile of mathematical machinery to really define and deal with differentials rigorously.

Comment: I am not sure I get your point about ` it's a measure of how much the change in x2 is not linear.` Could you please elaborate. BTW I see that your example about areas is better

Comment: (Just speaking intuitively) the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$, which represents the two skinny strips, and is the slope of the tangent line. (So it's the linear change.)  The little corner piece is the left-over bit which goes to zero squared-as-fast  the $dx$ does.  The smaller $dx$ is, the less the curve differs from a straight line.

Comment: The two skinny strips is $2xdx$ though. Do we neglect the dx?

Comment: The change in $x^2$ is about $2x \; dx$. Neglecting the $(dx)^2$, the change is linear _in $dx$_.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\mathrm{d}x$ should not be attempted to be taken too literally. [While it can be made precise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis) it's usually considered a relic from time when things were not as precisely defined as they are these days. You will run in all kinds of troubles if you try to naively assign it a deeper meaning.

I've never seen $\mathrm{d}x^2$ though.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated OP. I am talking about $(dx)^2$

Comment: $dx^2$ can appear in either differentiation w.r.t. $x^2$ or Riemann-Stieltjes integration w.r.t. $x^2$.